# When using 'import modulename' - where are variable values and functions (if any) stored?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

When we do `from modulename import function or variable`, then that function or variable gets loaded in calling modules namespace (local). Any change to variable is not global but only within the calling module (local).

When we do `import modulename`, then functions and variables get setup in the modulename namespace (global). Any change made to variable for example is globally visible.

I want to understand where exactly is the variable value and functions held? Is it in the sys modules dictionary or is there a namespace dictionary that holds the variable values and functions? Any articles or reference links on this subject will also be very helpful.

Comment: Note that if you import the module multiple times, but with different names, they share their contents.  For instance, `import foo` and `import foo as bar`.  Then `foo.x` and `bar.x` refer to the same variable, and changing it through one changes all of them.  But that's not the case if you import it into the current global namespace.  So if you do `from foo import *`, `import foo`, `import foo as bar`, then `foo.x` and `bar.x` refer to the same thing, but `x` is not aliased to either.

Comment: Yes this is what I have mentioned in the 1st and 2nd statement. Can you address my question please.

Comment: If you do `from foo import *`, then everything it imports is stored in the current module's global namespace.  You can access it as a `dict` through `globals()`.  If you import it into its own namespace (e.g. `import foo` or `import foo as bar`), then the first time the module is imported it creates a module object for it, with its own namespace.  Subsequent imports use the same module object.  For instance, if you do `foo is bar` the result is `True`.  The second import is equivalent to doing `bar = foo`.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand the difference between a variable name and a value in Python — it's a little different that it is in other languages like C/C++. See [Variables in Python](https://realpython.com/python-variables/). There's also a distinction between mutable and non-mutable values and what happens to the name(s) assigned to one when one is changed. It's important that you have a clear understanding of those concepts in order to make sense of how the different ways of importing things from modules work.

Comment: Also see [Why Variables in Python Are Different from Other Programming Languages?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/314808/why-variables-in-python-are-different-from-other-programming-languages)

Comment: I should add that even if you do `from foo import *`, it first imports the entire module, then it copies (via assignment) the requested items into the current global namespace.  So each module is imported at most once no matter how you do it.  You can see the imported modules by looking at `sys.modules`.  So `from foo import x` is equivalent to `import foo as anonymous_name`, then `x = anonymous_name.x`

Comment: from foo import x - this will bring the x in callers namespace. Whereas import foo as anonymous_name - this will not bring foo(alias anonymous_name) in callers namespace. But in the called modules (foo) namespace. Right? Then, x=anonymous_name.x will point caller modules local x to called modules x. But updating x wont update anonymous_name.x